# AWS Release Pipeline CodeCommit -> CodeBuild -> Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to create a release pipe line, where my source code is in CodeCommit and I use Codebuild for build and Deploying it into Beanstalk.

Codecommit -> CodeBuild -> Beanstalk

Actually this is a Java based application, I am trying to deploy .JAR file into Beanstalk(JAVA Platform). But in the above release pipeline. Codebuild generates some build artifacts, but they are not .JARs.

If I run the Codebuild seprately I get my Artifacts uploaded into S3 bucket. Please let me know if anyone successfully created above release pipeline.

I have also tried this way. i.e. creating two release pipeline

1) CodeCommit -> CodeBuild 
The above will build a .jar file and put it into S3

2) CodeCommit -> Beanstalk
The above S3 bucket will be added as a source, so if there is a new .JAR uploaded into respective S3 bucket, the deployment will be started.

This approach works fine.

Comment: anyone can help with this please ?